# What is the English term for "beschränkt Menge"?

Tags: translation-request, mathematical-german

I tried translating the word "beschränkt" and then google, for example, "limited set", but got no results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"beschränkt" can in this context be translated as "bounded" ("Schranke" = "bound")

General hints for the translation:

- Consider using [leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_en.html#/search=beschr%C3%A4nkt&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on&pos=0) which indicates mathematical terms with `[math]`.
- Another method for translating mathematical terms is searching for it in the [german wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beschr%C3%A4nktheit) and then going to the [english version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set) of the same article. Usually on the bottom left there is a whole list of languages.